# Using Template Binding of Knockout

Tags: jquery, css, knockout.js, jsfiddle, knockout-2.0

I have created a jsFiddle under which I am learning template binding of Knockout. For simple example, I was successful in applying template binding. However, when I created this jsfiddle example(as below) that includes css as well. It is not working for me. Where am I missing this.

```
<h2>Participants</h2>
Here are the participants:
<h3> Info Here
 <div class="span8">
 <div class="profile-container on" id="ResponsibilityGrid" data-bind="template: { name: 'responsibilities-template', foreach: ProductsInformation }">
                </div>
     </div><script type="text/html" id="responsibilities-template">
<ul>
    <li>
        <div tabindex="-1" data-bind="text: Name"></div>
        <div tabindex="-1"></div>
        <div class="icon" tabindex="-1"></div>
        <div class="sborder" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div class="sborder bottom" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;"></div>
    </li>

    <!-- ko foreach: Responsibilities -->
    <li>
        <div tabindex="-1" data-bind="text: Name"></div>
        <div class="icon" tabindex="-1"></div>
        <div class="sborder" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div class="sborder bottom" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div tabindex="-1" data-bind="text: Name" class="break-word"></div>
        <div class="icon" tabindex="-1"></div>
        <div class="sborder" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div class="sborder bottom" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;"></div>
    </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
</script>
```

here is the url of the jsfiddle:        https://jsfiddle.net/xejx5sh0/

I am a newbie in knockout.js and trying my best to learn it. I will request to ignore if I made any mistake in it. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: *"is not working"* is not a useful problem statement. What's going wrong? Do you see errors in the console?

Comment: We can't help you without your JavaScript. (Which must be **in** the question, not just linked.)

Comment: The HTML quoted in the question opens but never closes a template. There's no `</script>` end tag.

Comment: Use jsfiddle with http, not https. Otherwise KO library cannot be loaded. If you do so, this is what Chrome console tells your: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "template: function (){return { name:'person-template',data:buyer} }"
Message: buyer is not defined`

Comment: I am sorry for this connexo

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I dont get any errors, its just that only one name i.e Franklin is shown in the Result Window. and no css is loaded

Comment: Where have you defined `buyer` and `seller`?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
<div tabindex="-1" data-bind="text: Name"></div>
```

with

```
<div tabindex="-1" data-bind="text: name"></div>
```

and in your JSFiddle you have called a function on click event inside a template.

```
<li data-bind="click: GetQuickLookProfile">
```

but this GetQuickLookProfile function doesnot exist on javascript. u have to remove that data-bind or make GetQuickLookProfile to make it work.
hope this will help.